# Impact of General Styles on Individual Block Styles (div)

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQbYj.png)I have a block of code that creates a modal window and styles for it. I need to make sure that the styles of the modal window are not affected by the rest of the table styles, because the modal window is not displayed as expected. For example, there is a style for the body and because of this my modal window does not appear on the entire page, since the body contains a style for maximum width. I need to make the styles for the modal window work separately from the general styles and they do not affect each other. In picture one you can see that the window opens halfway, and in picture two there is a style for the body that prevents it from opening completely. Below is the modal window code and its styles.
Modal Window:

```
  // Создаем HTML для модального окна
  const modalHTML = `
<!-- Модальное окно  -->
<div id="mmyMModal" class="mmodalWWindow">
<div class="mmodal-ccontent">
  <p id="eerror-ttitle" class="mmodal-ttext"></p>
  <div class="success_icon">
    <p>X</p>
  </div>
  <span class="ccloseWWindow">&times;</span>
  <p id="mmodalTText" class="mmodal-ttext"></p>
</div>
</div>
`;
```

Style:

```
  const modalStyle = document.createElement('style');
  modalStyle.textContent = `
#mmyMModal {
display: none;
position: fixed;
z-index: 9999;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: auto;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
animation: fadeIn 0.5s ease;
}

#mmyMModal .mmodal-ccontent {
position: relative;
background-color: #fefefe;
margin: 15% auto;
padding: 20px;
border: 1px solid #888;
width: 40%;
max-width: 600px;
text-align: center;
font-weight: 800;
color: black;
border-radius: 10px;
font: 700 48px/64px Roboto, sans-serif;
}

#mmyMModal .ccloseWWindow {
color: #aaa;
position: absolute;
top: -10px;
right: 10px;
font-size: 28px;
font-weight: bold;
cursor: pointer;
z-index: 9999;
}

#mmyMModal .ccloseWWindow:hover,
#mmyMModal .ccloseWWindow:focus {
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
}

#mmyMModal .mmodal-ttext {
font-size: 24px;
line-height: 1.6;
}

#mmyMModal .success_icon {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
margin: 20px auto;
}

#mmyMModal .success_icon p {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
font-size: 50px;
color: #fff;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border-radius: 50%;
text-align: center;
line-height: 100px;
transform: scale(1);
margin: 0;
transition: all 0.3s ease;
position: relative;
}

#mmyMModal .success_icon p::before {
content: "";
font-size: 50px;
color: #fff;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}

#mmyMModal .success_icon p::after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border-radius: 50%;
background-color: #ef2c2c;
z-index: -1;
}
```

I tried using priority, pseudo-elements: before, after and nothing helped. I expected modal window styles to work regardless of other styles

Comment: You are mentioning a "picture one" and "picture two", but there are no images in your question. Also the code you provide is not sufficient to give a reliable answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the element.style.cssText to assign the styles to that element.

In your case,

```js
const modalHTML = `
<!-- Модальное окно  -->
<div id="mmyMModal" class="mmodalWWindow">
<div class="mmodal-ccontent">
  <p id="eerror-ttitle" class="mmodal-ttext"></p>
  <div class="success_icon">
    <p>X</p>
  </div>
  <span class="ccloseWWindow">&times;</span>
  <p id="mmodalTText" class="mmodal-ttext"></p>
</div>
</div>
`;

const elem = document.createElement('div');
elem.innerHTML = modalHTML;

const styles = `
#mmyMModal {
display: none;
position: fixed;
z-index: 9999;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: auto;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
animation: fadeIn 0.5s ease;
}

#mmyMModal .mmodal-ccontent {
position: relative;
background-color: #fefefe;
margin: 15% auto;
padding: 20px;
border: 1px solid #888;
width: 40%;
max-width: 600px;
text-align: center;
font-weight: 800;
color: black;
border-radius: 10px;
font: 700 48px/64px Roboto, sans-serif;
}

#mmyMModal .ccloseWWindow {
color: #aaa;
position: absolute;
top: -10px;
right: 10px;
font-size: 28px;
font-weight: bold;
cursor: pointer;
z-index: 9999;
}

#mmyMModal .ccloseWWindow:hover,
#mmyMModal .ccloseWWindow:focus {
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
}

#mmyMModal .mmodal-ttext {
font-size: 24px;
line-height: 1.6;
}

#mmyMModal .success_icon {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
margin: 20px auto;
}

#mmyMModal .success_icon p {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
font-size: 50px;
color: #fff;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border-radius: 50%;
text-align: center;
line-height: 100px;
transform: scale(1);
margin: 0;
transition: all 0.3s ease;
position: relative;
}

#mmyMModal .success_icon p::before {
content: "";
font-size: 50px;
color: #fff;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}

#mmyMModal .success_icon p::after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border-radius: 50%;
background-color: #ef2c2c;
z-index: -1;
}
`

//Now you can assign the style to that element.

elem.style.cssText = styles;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: The modal window now does not open at all))